# TableAdapter.UpdateAll(Dataset) is updating all columns in the table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

C#, VS2010

Created a Datagridviewer and Drag/Dropped the Database table onto a windows form.

Created the "Update CommanTex":

```
UPDATE       minerals

SET                Tritanium = @p0, Pyerite = @p1, Mexallon = @p2, Isogen = @p3, Nocxium =    

@p4, Zydrine = @p5, Megacyte = @p6, Morphite = @p7
```

This seems to update every field in the database when I edit via the DataGridViewer and save using the save button auto-generated by VS2010.

How do I get the Datagridviewer to only update the fields that were changed?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# -" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

That's how `TableAdapter` and `DataAdapter` work. They will always update every column.

An ORM like Entity Framework will generate the SQL at runtime, so can decide to only generate SET clauses for columns which have changed.